# How can I make sure SpecFlow features do not run simultaneously?

Tags: xunit, specflow

I have built some SpecFlow scenarios to test features of a HTTP REST interface. When I run the features separately, they work fine, but when run all together, some of the scenarios sometimes fail. The failure is that there is no reply from the REST interface webserver.

The first step of all features is to start the REST interface webserver, but I reckon this can fail if another scenario is still running, or not yet completely finished and the listening port cannot be bound.

Is there a way to make sure the different features run nicely after eachother?

Comment: This depends on the test runner and the code in the tests. Unfortunately we cannot answer your question without more information. Can you include a [repro]?

Comment: I am using the xUnit runner. To make an MRE would be hard, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: If the REST service listens on the same port, it represents a shared resource. Unless all calls are idempotent, parallel tests will be impossible.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I reckoned that, so the question is how can I make sure these tests run sequentially?

Comment: Test order should not matter. Each test should be capable of being run in any order. Unless you meant "how to make sure these tests are not run concurrently?" In that case, it depends on the test runner and the code driving your tests.

Comment: @GregBurghardt that is what I meant. Order indeed doesn't matter.

Comment: Does each REST service instance have its own database? Running tests concurrently means the full tech stack needs to be replicated for each test, not just a new instance of the REST service.

Comment: @GregBurghardt there is no database. And I do start everything before each test. I found the setting to not have multiple tests run at once, and they all pass now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the [xUnit documentation site](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files). I added a `xunit.runner.json` file and added

```
 "maxParallelThreads": 1
```

to the config. Only one SpecFlow test is run at the time now.